# How to click on a specific button when multiple are present on a webpage

Tags: javascript, playwright

There are two buttons on a webpage called "Place Order". The first button html code looks like this :

`<button class="mod-ncss-btn ncss-btn-accent fs14-sm ncss-brand pt3-sm prl5-sm pb3-sm pt2-lg pb2-lg d-sm-b d-md-ib u-uppercase u-rounded mod-button-width">Place Order</button>`

The second button html code looks like this:
`<button class="d-lg-ib d-sm-h fs14-sm ncss-brand ncss-btn-accent pb2-lg pb3-sm prl5-sm pt2-lg pt3-sm u-uppercase">Place Order</button>`

I am using Playwright on Javascript to try to click on the second button but can not get it to succeed so far. Both the buttons have dynamically changing classes so I am using this line to find the button and click on it:
`await page.click('//button[contains(text(),"Place Order")]);`

The problem I am having is that since both of these buttons are present on the webpage at the same time, I am clicking the first "Place Order" button. I am trying to click on the second "Place Order" button but have not succeeded since my code clicks on the first. Can someone show me how I can click on the second "Place Order" button instead of clicking the first? I am still new to Playwright and constantly learning everyday. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The main idea here is that you can use multiple selectors to select elements on your page. I decided to assign `ids` to the buttons for the most uniqueness, because the classes you provided were too many and most of them aren't unique

```js
const buttonOne = document.querySelector('[data-button=one]');
const buttonTwo = document.querySelector('[data-button=two]');

buttonOne.addEventListener('click', e => alert(e.target.innerText));

buttonTwo.addEventListener('click', e => alert(e.target.innerText));

buttonOne.click();
buttonTwo.click();
```

```html
<button data-button="one">Button One</button>
<button data-button="two">Button Two</button>
```

Comment: If the buttons had ids then it would make it easy for me to scrape using playwright, but this is not the case as seen in the html code I provided for both buttons. This is my problem, I can't find anything unique about the buttons to separate them. The class changed every time the page is loaded which is why I can't use that.

Comment: Then you could use `data-attributes`. Like setting `data-buton="one"` for the first button and `data-button="two"` for the second